# How to install default/stock Terminal app?

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave

I uninstalled the default/stock Terminal app via AppCleaner. How to get the default/stock Terminal back without reinstalling Mojave?

Comment: Default apps are protected by SIP so you shouldn’t have been able to delete it without some complex steps prior.  How exactly did you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore it from your backup. Because you wouldn't start deleting bits of the system with a third-party app without making sure you had a backup.

Failing that, you can reinstall the OS over the top of your existing installation, and all your files, apps and settings will still be in place. This will make sure that anything else important that ApplCleaner has deleted will be restored.

Some people do this from time to time, just to make sure nothing's got corrupted or missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to access the terminal app without reloading the operating system. If you have terminal on another machine you may be able to copy the app to your computer.

An easier solution would be to use [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com). Its a terminal emulator like terminal but with more features. Its considered by many as a better emulator than Terminal. I use it myself in place of the Terminal app.

Comment: I do have another Mac machine, will copying the Terminal app via AirDrop work?

I'm using iTerm2 that's why I uninstalled the default/stock Terminal app. But I'm using Visual Studio for Mac & is looking for the default/stock Terminal app which I  uninstalled...

Comment: If you can air drop the Terminal app I would try that and see if it works.

Comment: You said, "I don't think there is a way to access the terminal app without reloading the operating system." and that is not at all true! It can be copied from another system running the same version of the OS it was delete from, (zip up a copy and move the zipped copy) or extracted out of a macOS Installer of the same version without reinstalling the whole OS. I use [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) for extraction operations such as that. Note that I am not affiliated with the developer of Pacifist, just a satisfied paid customer.

Comment: I also said if you have it on another machine you may try copying it.